# Can you only buy one extra die with the The Calm Before The Storm destiny square?

Tags: claustrophobia

On the Board of Destiny for the Demon player, there is a destiny square that allows you to use any die to buy an extra die next turn. Can you only buy only one extra die with this ability, or can you use multiple dice to buy more than a single die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only buy a single die, per Threat Phase.
The Destiny Board says:

> **Any Die Score**: Roll an extra Die of Destiny during the next Threat Phase.

Rules page 8

> (red) **The Calm Before The Storm** (red) allows the Demon player to roll an extra Die of Destiny during their next Threat phase.
>
> Abilities printed in (red) can only be selected once per <s>game</s> Threat Phase (Errata: [claustrophobia-theboardgame.com/fr/?p=441](http://claustrophobia-theboardgame.com/fr/?p=441)). There are no limitations for the Abilities printed in (black).

Comment: From the errata (en Francais) at http://www.claustrophobia-theboardgame.com/fr/?p=441 red abilities are limited to once per threat phase, not once per game.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. We were playing this wrong for a while. It became especially clear on the mission where you delve into the sewers towards the Demon with 10 HP, and the Demon player has nothing better to do than buy events and extra dice (for 12+ die totals, instant damage). The demon player was rolling 4 extra dice one turn (incorrectly of course).